# How can I invalidate and login using realm login-config in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication

I have a realm and a login page `/login` that provides the form for logging into the realm. I would like a user to be able to navigate to the login page directly and log-in for the first time causing a redirect to the home page of the app, or log in as a new user (or the same user) which also sends them to the home page of the app. There are two problems here:

1) If a user logged-in travels to the login page directly and attempts to login as another user, I get a 404 error `The requested resource (/myapp/j_security_check) is not available.`

2) If a user logs in for the first time I get an error 400 saying `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Invalid direct reference to form login page).`

Is it possible to use the login form in the way I describe or will I have to manually log them in with a second login page through a servlet? If I have to create my own, how can I log them in so that tomcat continues to manage the authentication (I would keep the login-config form for cases when a user tries to access a restricted page without logging in)?

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is not possible to use the `<login-config>` form in this way. However, the servlet 3.0 spec has given us access to a few helpful functions that allow you to write your own servlet that can log a user in. `HttpServletRequest#login` and `HttpServletRequest#logout` let you log a user in an out of the realm associated with the servlet context. Further, you can check if a user is logged into the realm by checking the user principal object with `HttpServletRequest#getUserPrincipals`.

I set up my custom login page using these functions in a servlet at the path `/login` and I also have a near identical servlet/jsp that the realm authenticator will forward to but the difference is that the form will submit to the `j_security_check`. There is probably a fancy way to reuse the first login servlet/jsp and just change the `action` attribute and fields in the form, but I'll leave that for another day.